# Source of Ajahn Chah quote

Tags: theravada, reference-request, suffering, thinking

I'd like to read the context for the following quote from Ajahn Chah:

> I want those who train with me to see the truth, not just read the
> scriptures. I want them to see if their hearts have been completely
> liberated from conceptual thinking.

It's from a calendar (October 2016) put out by forestsangha.org.

Also, an explanation of the meaning of the statement would be very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to come from "[Unshakeable Peace](https://www.dhammatalks.net/Books2/Ajahn_Chah_UnShakeable_Peace.htm)" by Ven. Ajahn Chah, though not verbatim. You can read the full dhamma talk on that link.

> When I train my disciples, I train them to practice like this. Because
> I want them to see the truth, rather than just read what's in the
> scriptures; I want them to see if their hearts have been liberated
> from conceptual thinking.

Comment: Thanks so much. 
A footnote says: "This same Dhamma talk by Ajahn Chah was formerly printed as a different translation under the title The Key to Liberation." 
That translation says: *Whenever I teach the monastic community, I teach that way – because I want you to see the truth. I don’t want you just to see what’s in the books. I want you to see for yourselves, in your own minds, whether you have been liberated from your defiled thoughts or not.*